# SVN error: Subcommand 'help' doesn't accept option '--no-auth-cache'

Tags: linux, svn, centos

SVN client doesn't works on my CentOS development server

CLI SVN client call produces the same error.

```
$ svn revert ./foo.txt
Subcommand 'revert' doesn't accept option '--no-auth-cache'
Type 'svn help help' for usage.

$ svn help
Subcommand 'help' doesn't accept option '--no-auth-cache'
Type 'svn help help' for usage.

...
```

So it produces the same error each time I'm trying to call the svn client from CLI

I'm able to "svn list" and "svn status". But there is no ability to "svn revert" my changes and call "svn help".

I've tried to investigate the problem and found that svn client always tries to use "--no-auth-cache" switch *somehow* automatically without explicit mention of this switch.

But as this switch is not available for such local commands like "revert" it produces that kind of error.

It looks like this problem somehow related to svn client configuration/setup.

I've even tried to remove the entire client configuration data directory:
$ rm -rf ~/.subversion

but it doesn't helps.

Comment: Thanks guys! It was alias, dummy me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a script ( or an alias?) in your path that is calling svn with the extra flag.

For example an alias set like:

```
alias svn='svn --no-auth-cache'
```

will give this problem.

Try calling svn directly like `/bin/svn` or wherever it is installed

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using vanilla SVN? Maybe someone setup an alias?

Try `apropos svn` to find out where your svn client is installed, and execute that file directly (example `/usr/bin/svn help`).

Check `alias` for aliases.

Is there anything in `~/.subversion/config`? Try renaming or removing that directory.

#### Edit:

To circumvent possible aliases, try executing `\svn` instead of `svn`.

Answer (score 1):

Concur with others; the output of `type -all svn` will indicate which svn command will execute, and which others it shadows.

Comment: Yes, `type --all` forgot to mention. That should help the figure it out!